# Calling function on subclass of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I can't really understand why I am getting this error when I call a function on a subclass of UILabel.
I have in AppDelegate

```
class CascadingLabel: UILabel {
func cascade(){
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.alpha = 1
        }
    }
func initializeText(){
    print("[OUT21] Init")
}
}
```

In ViewController,

```
@IBOutlet weak var Intro1: CascadingLabel!
 func initializeText(){
    Intro1.initializeText() //Here I am getting error!
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("[OUT21] OpeningScreen opened")
    initializeText()
}
```

The app crashes, yielding error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1b3900ec8)
```

UPDATE ANSWER: Thanks to @ChristianAbella for the answer here. I didn't indicate the class in the Storyboard.

Comment: did you connect your Intro1 variable to the storyboard layout?

Comment: Yes I did. The grey circle is there.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the crash?

Comment: The line in viewdidload that says initialize text

Comment: did you change the class name of the label in the Custom Class property in the storyboard to CascadingLabel?

Comment: @ChristianAbella that was my mistake. Thanks for helping.

Comment: no worries. happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting following error

[image]

Everything is fine just assign your class name to UILabel in storyboard

[image]